# Unable to open pdf fetched from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to upload and fetch pdf file from firebase to android . the app succesfully uploads pdf to firebase but when i try to click on the retrieved file from firebase it returns to main activity

Here is the code of view uploads activity

I have added all the dependancies and user permissions
Can anyone help me with this

```
package com.example.firebasestorage;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class ViewUploadsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ListView listView;
    
        //database reference to get uploads data
        DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    
        //list to store uploads data
        List<Upload> uploadList;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_uploads);
            uploadList = new ArrayList<>();
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    
    
            //adding a clicklistener on listview
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    //getting the upload
                    Upload upload = uploadList.get(i);
    
                    //Opening the upload file in browser using the upload url
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(upload.getUrl()));
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    
    
            //getting the database reference
            mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);
    
            //retrieving upload data from firebase database
            mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        uploadList.add(upload);
                    }
    
                    String[] uploads = new String[uploadList.size()];
    
                    for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
                        uploads[i] = uploadList.get(i).getName();
                    }
    
                    //displaying it to list
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uploads);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    
                }
            });
    
        }
    }
```

I am getting these error in logcat

```
    2021-07-16 19:49:05.372 486-486/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
    2021-07-16 19:49:05.372 486-486/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
    2021-07-16 19:49:06.473 493-493/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
    2021-07-16 19:49:06.473 493-493/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-07-16 19:49:15.296 1205-20692/com.google.android.gms E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
```

Comment: Does your app crash?

Comment: No, It returns to main activity

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: I am getting this errors in logcat

Comment: I have updated question with errors

Comment: I cannot see any Firebase errors there. Are you sure you have added the right error?

Comment: Ya these are the errors which i am getting and the app crashes when i try to view pdf

Comment: None of them will produce a crash.